# How to find the equation of a line, tangent to a circle, that passes through a given external point

Tags: circles, tangent-line

I am given the equation of a circle: $(x + 2)^2 + (y + 7)^2 = 25$. The radius is $5$. Center of the circle: $(-2, -7)$.

Two lines tangent to this circle pass through point $(4, -3)$, which is outside of said circle. How would I go about finding one of the equations of the lines tangent to the circle?

I haven't started calculus, so I ask for advice fitting for someone starting a topic like this.

Comment: Note that you don't need to tell us what the center of the circle is, that information is easily extracted from the equation for the circle. Also, you speak of "*the* lines tangent to this circle" as though there were only those two, but there are an infinite number of tangent lines for any given circle.

Comment: **Hint:** a line is tangent to a circle if and only if it is perpendicular to the radius (that is, to the line containing the center and the tangent point).

Comment: I'm not sure i follow that @Sigur, if i draw a circle $C$ and a point $P$ external to $C$, then a line that I draw from $P$ to  $C$ that is tangent to $C$ isn't perpendicular to the line drawn from the origin of $C$ to $P$. So I've obviously misunderstood something.

Comment: @baxx, should be from the center of the circle to the tangent point, not to $P$.

Comment: By Joachimsthal the two tangents can be found by factoring $s\cdot s_{11}-s_1^2$ shifted so that $(4,-3)$ is sent to the origin $$((x+2+4)^2+(y+7-3)^2-25) ((4+2)^2+(-3+7)^2-25)-(4(x+4) + 2(x+4+4) -3(y-3) + 7 (y-3-3) + 28)^2$$ or $-9 x^2 - 48 x y + 11 y^2$ which when we translate back yield the tangents $$-(-3 (x-4) + (-8+5 \sqrt3)(y+3)) (-3 (x-4) +(-8-5 \sqrt3)(y+3))=0.$$

Answer (score 12):

A useful technique for this situation which avoids using calculus goes like this:

Find the equation of the line through the point $(4,-3)$ with gradient $k$, and then use this (linear) equation to substitute into the equation of the circle to get a quadratic. The two roots of this quadratic would give the 2 points of intersection of the line with the circle, but in our case, we want to know the values of $k$ for which the quadratic has a double root (i.e. the 2 points of intersection are actually coincident). Use the standard condition ($b^2=4ac$) for a double root of a quadratic.

In your case, the equation of the line through $(4,-3)$ with gradient $k$ is $y+3 = k(x-4)$, or $y+7 = k(x-4)+4$. Substituting this into the equation of the circle gives:

$$(x+2)^2 + (k(x-4)+4)^2 = 25$$

So you need to rearrange this quadratic in $x$ and find out which values of $k$ give double roots.

Comment: "without using calculus", how would you do it with calculus?

Answer (score 10):

Without any loss of generality we can draw a tangent to a circle
with centre $C\equiv(C_x,C_y)$ and radius $r$ and choose a point
$P\equiv(P_x,P_y)$ on the tangent so that its distance from the centre is
$\overline{CP}\equiv d$ with $d \ge r$.

[image]

From the sketch above we recognize that the tangency points can be
described as the sums of vectors, i.e.,

$$ \overrightarrow{OT_1} = \overrightarrow{OC}+
  \frac{a}{d}\,\overrightarrow{CP}+
  \frac{b}{d}\,\overrightarrow{CP}',\qquad
  \overrightarrow{OT_2} = \overrightarrow{OC}+
  \frac{a}{d}\,\overrightarrow{CP}-
  \frac{b}{d}\,\overrightarrow{CP}'$$

where the prime in $\overrightarrow{CP}'$ represents a 90⁰
anticlockwise rotation of the vector.

Because our task is now to determine $a/d$ and $b/d$, we observe that
the triangles $CT_1C'$ and $CPT_1$ are similar so that, with the position
$\rho=r/d$, we have

$$\frac{a}{r} = \frac{r}{d} \implies \frac{a}{d}=\left(\frac{r}{d}\right)^2 =\rho^2$$

and

$$\frac{b}{r} = \frac{R}{d} \implies \frac{b}{d}=\frac{rR}{d^2}
=\rho\frac Rd$$

but $R=\sqrt{d^2-r^2}$ and eventually we can write

$$ \frac{b}{d}= \rho\sqrt{1-\rho^2}.$$

From the last relation we recognize 1) that a real solution requires
$\rho\le1$ (i.e., $P$ is not inside the circle) and 2) that for
$\rho=1$ the point $P$ is on the circumference and the tangency points
degenerate into $P$.

The OP can now compute the tangency points, etc.

E.g., in Python 3 (that is as close to pseudo-code as it could possibly be...)

```
from math import sqrt
# Data Section, change as you need #
Cx, Cy = -2, -7                    #
r = 5                              #
Px, Py =  4, -3                    #
# ################################ #
dx, dy = Px-Cx, Py-Cy
dxr, dyr = -dy, dx
d = sqrt(dx**2+dy**2)
if d >= r :
    rho = r/d
    ad = rho**2
    bd = rho*sqrt(1-rho**2)
    T1x = Cx + ad*dx + bd*dxr
    T1y = Cy + ad*dy + bd*dyr
    T2x = Cx + ad*dx - bd*dxr
    T2y = Cy + ad*dy - bd*dyr

    print('The tangent points:')
    print('\tT1≡(%g,%g),  T2≡(%g,%g).'%(T1x, T1y, T2x, T2y))
    if (d/r-1) < 1E-8:
        print('P is on the circumference')
    else:
        print('The equations of the lines P-T1 and P-T2:')
        print('\t%+g·y%+g·x%+g = 0'%(T1x-Px, Py-T1y, T1y*Px-T1x*Py))
        print('\t%+g·y%+g·x%+g = 0'%(T2x-Px, Py-T2y, T2y*Px-T2x*Py))
else:
    print('''\
Point P≡(%g,%g) is inside the circle with centre C≡(%g,%g) and radius r=%g.
No tangent is possible...''' % (Px, Py, Cx, Cy, r))
```

Executing the program yields

```
The tangent points:
    T1≡(-1.1139,-2.07914),  T2≡(2.88314,-8.0747).
The equations of the lines P-T1 and P-T2:
    -5.1139·y-0.920857·x-11.6583 = 0
    -1.11686·y+5.0747·x-23.6494 = 0
```

Comment: Oh! this is the way i am looking for (programming). Thank you!

Comment: "pseudo-code" usually implies untested.  I.E. there COULD be an error.  Am I correct that bd = rho*sqrt(1-rho**2) could be simplified to bd = rho*sqrt(1-ad) ?  Also, is there a typo somewhere?  AS Listed, when I run this, I get answers that look like the signs of all 4 values are wrong.  Is this the "correct" code:
        T1x = OriginPoint.x - ad*dx + bd*dxr,
        T2x = OriginPoint.x - ad*dx - bd*dxr,
        T1y = OriginPoint.y - ad*dy + bd*dyr,
        T2y = OriginPoint.y - ad*dy - bd*dyr

Comment: @bielawski I was able to test my code in a limited set of cases, as it's not pseudo code but executable Python3 code, at the same I'm not claiming a full coverage of every possible corner case, if you can show an issue please post an answer where you show the failures of your method.

Comment: @bielawski The proposed simplification introduces the term `1-ad` that represents the difference between a non dimensional number and an area.

Comment: @bielawski In my (limited) testing I have not seen the problems you've mentioned. If you don't post your code (and I mean, not in a comment where it's essentially unreadable…) and the errors it produces, how can I tell if there is a typo in it? I forgot to mention, thank you very much for the interest you are showing for this old answer.

Comment: I had no idea the comment functionality would mangle what I typed so badly.  I'm quite sure it did muddy this conversation.  In any case, my 'translation' of the code into OpenScad (3d modeling software) only involved adding commas to the end of lines and converting multi-assignments to individual assignments.   I don't speak Python but I DID need to change the 2 "Cx +" and "Cy+" statements to "Cx-" and "Cy -" for the resulting objects to be correct.  If you have confidence in the code I'm happy to assume the trouble I fixed is strictly local to my translation.

Answer (score 6):

One possible approach would be the following:
1) Denote by $A$ the point $(4,-3)$, by $O$ the center of the circle, and by $P_1,P_2$ the two points on the circle in which the corresponding tangent line intersects the circle. Then both the triangles $AOP_1$ and $AOP_2$ are right, with hypotenuse $AO$.
2) The length of $AO$ is $\sqrt{(-2-4)^2+(-7-(-3))^2}=\sqrt{36+16}=\sqrt{52}$. The length of $OP_1$ and of $OP_2$ is the radius, and therefore equal to $5$. So, using the Pythagorean theorem, we get: 
$$|AP_1|=|AP_2|=\sqrt{|OA|^2-r^2}=\sqrt{52-25}=\sqrt{27}$$
3) From here you can find both $P_1$ and $P_2$ - they are the points of intersections of the given circle with the circle of radius $\sqrt{27}$ around $(4,-3)$.
4) Now find the equations of two lines passing through given points.

Answer (score 2):

My work out

1. PC gradient:

   (-3+7)/(4+2)=tan(33.7°)
2. PC distance:

   √((-3+7)²+(4+2)²)=√52
3. ∠CPQ = arcsin(5/√52)=43.9°
4. Equations of tangent passing through
   PQ & PR

   (Y+3)/(X-4)=tan(33.7±43.9)

Answer (score 1):

Assume the point where the tangent touches the circle is 
$(x_1,y_2)$, then this point satisfies the equation of 
the circle and the equation

$$ y'= \frac{y_1+3}{x_1-4 }\longrightarrow (*).$$

Now, you need to find $y'$ and evaluate it at the point 
$(x_1,y_1)$ and subs. back in (*), so you end up having two
Equations in two variables. Solve them to find the point 
$(x_1,y_1)$ and finaly you will have two points that required 
to find the tangent plane.

Answer (score 1):

The equation of any line passing through $(4,-3)$ is $$\frac{y+3}{x-4}=m\iff mx-y-4m-3=0$$ where $m$ is the gradient

Now, the perpendicular distance of tangent to center of circle = radius of circle

Do you know how to calculate the perpendicular distance of a line from the point?

Observe that the values of $m$

$(i)$ will be distinct real (hence, two tangents) if the point lies outside the circle,

$(ii)$ will be equal real (hence, one tangent) if the point lies on the circle,

$(iii)$ will be distinct imaginary (hence, no real tangents) if the point lies inside the circle,

See $12(b)$ [here](http://goo.gl/yW2pFx)

Answer (score 1):

We can use the formula for the distance from a point to a line. The distance between a line $ax + by + c = 0$ and a point $(x_0, y_0)$ is
$$\left| \frac{a x_0 + b y_0 + c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} \right|.$$

The line of tangency that passes the point $(4, -3)$ has equation $y+3 = m(x-4)$ for some slope $m$. So we just need to find $m$. Note that this equation can be written as
$$mx - y -4m -3 = 0.$$

The distance between the center of the circle $(-2, -7)$ and the tangent line $mx - y -4m -3 = 0$ can be found from the formula above. This distance also equals to the radius of the circle, which is $5$. Hence

$$\left| \frac{m(-2) + (-1)(-7) +(-4m -3)}{\sqrt{m^2 + 1}} \right| = 5.$$
Rearranging we have
$$|-6m + 4| = 5 \sqrt{m^2+1}. $$
Squaring and rearranging, we get the quadratic equation
$$11m^2 - 48m - 9 = 0$$
with solutions
$$m = \frac{24\pm15\sqrt{3}}{11}.$$

Therefore, the required equations for the tangent lines are
$$y+3 = \frac{24+15\sqrt{3}}{11}\cdot(x-4)$$
and
$$y+3 = \frac{24-15\sqrt{3}}{11}\cdot(x-4).$$

Comment: It seems that this is the quickest way.... +1

Answer (score 0):

Let $P(x,y)$ be one of the points at which a tangent line fron $Q(4,-3)$ to the circle
$$(x+2)^2+(y+7)^2=25\tag 1$$
touches. Then $P(x,y)$ satifies the equation $(1)$ since it is on that circle. We need another equation to solve $x$ and $y$.

(Informal) Geometric meaning of the derivative: The derivative of a curve at a point is equal to the slope of the tangent line at that point: $m=y'$.

(Informal) Implicit Differentiation: If $F(x,y)=c$ then $y'=-\frac{F_x}{F_y}$ where $F_x$ and $F_y$ are partial derivatives.

Analytic geometry: The slope of the line passing through $P(x,y)$ and $Q(x_0,y_0)$ is $m=\frac{y-y_0}{x-x_0}$.

From the ingredients above, we have
$$m=\frac{y-(-3)}{x-4}=-\frac{x+2}{y+7}=y'$$
or
$$(x-1)^2+(y+5)^2=13.\tag 2$$
Now it is clear that $P$ is one of the intersection points of the circles $(1)$ and $(2)$. If we substract the equation $(2)$ from $(1)$ we find the radical axis
$$y=-\frac32x-\frac{15}4\tag3$$
of these circles passing through the intersection points which are the tangency points we are looking for.
Substituting $(3)$ in $(1)$ or $(2)$ we have
$$52x^2-92x-167=0.\tag4$$

For the remaining computations I had to use WolframAlpha:

Solving $(4)$, WA finds that the $x$-coordinate of $P$ can be
$$x=\frac{23}{26}\pm\frac{15\sqrt3}{13}$$
with the corresponding $y$-coordinates
$$y=-\frac{66}{13}\mp\frac{45\sqrt3}{26}.$$
The tangent lines searched for are
$$\frac{y+3}{x-4}=\frac{24\pm15\sqrt3}{11}.$$

Answer (score -3):

Let eq of tangents be y= mx+ c then it passes through point (4,-3) 
So -3=4m+c let it put aside
Now tangent touches circle so radius = distance between centre and line
5 = |-2m+7+c|/(m^2+1)^1/2 
By solving we get
11 m^2 +24m=9
We get two values of m
These are slopes of lines`enter preformatted text here`
We can equation of lines and angle between lines
This is my idea

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773).