# Find a tangent lines to the circle that tangent lines cross (4,1). $x^2+y^2+4x-2y-11=0$

Tags: derivatives, implicit-differentiation

Problem: Find a tangent lines to the cirlce that tangent lines cross (4,1).
$$x^2+y^2+4x-2y-11=0$$
I try to find $y'$ and I get $\frac{-x-2}{y-1}$. And idea after that was using $y-y_0=\frac{-x_0-2}{y_0-1}(x-x_0)$.

Comment: See also : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543496/how-to-find-the-equation-of-a-line-tangent-a-circle-and-a-given-point-outside-of

Answer (score 1):

You working out is fine. Substitute in the values for $(x_0,y_0)$ and you should will notice you get an infinite gradient. Have a think about what that means.

It is a vertical line. So the answer is simply $x=4$.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
  x^2 + y^2 + 4x - 2y - 11 &= 0\\[0.3cm]
  2x + 2yy' + 4 - 2y' &= 0\\[0.3cm]
  (2y-2)y' &= -2x-4\\[0.3cm]
  y' &= -\frac{x+2}{y-1}
\end{align}
Looks like your $y'$ is correct!

Next, plug $(x,y) = (4,1)$ into $y'$ to find the actual slope..  Ah, but we can't let $y = 1$ because then we get $0$ in the denominator.  So, tell me, what does this mean about the tangent line at that point?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: It might have been based on your first answer which didn't address the problem the OP was having with the evaluation of the gradient.

Comment: The downvote came quite a bit after that, though, unless it just took a while for me to be notified.  Meh, oh well.  Haters gonna hate.