# Equation of tangent line of circle $(x-10)^2+(y-10)^2=100$ at point (30,10)

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I tried to solve using a formula in my textbook, however it is just appropriate if the point is on the circle. I just realized that the point (30,10) is outside the circle. Please your help.

Comment: Similar question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543496/how-to-find-the-equation-of-a-line-tangent-a-circle-and-a-given-point-outside-of

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=m(x-30)+10$ . We have 
$$(x-10)^2+(m(x-30))^2=100$$
 as a result
$$(m^2+1)x^2-(60m+20)x+900m=0$$
and
$$\Delta=(60m+20)^2-3600m(m^2+1)=0$$

Comment: $$400(3m+1)^2-3600m(m^2+1)=0$$ . thus $$9m^3-9m^2+3m-1=0$$ In other words $$9\left(m-\frac 13\right)^3-\frac 23=0$$

Answer (score 0):

$y-10=m(x-30)$ is an equation of the tangent line or $mx-y-30m+10=0$.

Thus, $\frac{|10m-10-30m+10|}{\sqrt{m^2+1}}=10$ or $m^2=\frac{1}{3}$ and the rest is smooth.